# How to "Paste" two Two-Dimensional Arrays together?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have two 2D arrays, like this:

```java
int[][] arrayone = {
  {1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 1}
}
```

```java
int[][] arraytwo = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

So, let's say I want to paste them like images, pasting the first one (arrayone) at the center (coordinates (x / 2, y / 2)) or any other coordinates I would like, so the result would be:

CENTER:

```java
int[][] arrayresult = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
  {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
  {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

Coordinates (4, 3):

```java
int[][] arrayresult = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

Coordinates (2, 3):

```java
int[][] arrayresult = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
  {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

You got the point. Oh, and this is considering that I paste arrayone on arraytwo, not arraytwo on top of array one. I was thinking about making a system that gets the center of arrayone, calculates the other coordinates around and relative to the center and puts the center on the coordinates that are specified at arraytwo and the others relative to those coordinates, but I am not sure what to do. Thank you.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Just write two for loops iterating over the array to be inserted and basically copy `destination[xIndex + xOffset][yIndex + yOffset] = source[xIndex][yIndex]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

- `A` be the smaller matrix (`arrayone`)
- `B` be the bigger matrix (`arraytwo`)
- `C` be a matrix equal to B (`arrayresult`) (`int [][] C = B;`)
- `x` and `y` the inputed coordinates of the upper left corner of where to paste the matrix `A` in `C`

You perform a nested double loop in `C` matrix, starting from (`x,y`) and going on for as much as `A` is big, pasting in `C` the corresponding values from `A` at every inner iteration (aka for every cell).

Let the code speak for itself:

```
if(x + A.length <= B.length && y + A.length <= B.length){   //Check for legal input
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
        C[x+i][y+j]= A[i][j];
    }
}
return C
```

Hope I helped!